# Raspberry Pi with Kali Linux won't boot to GUI

Tags: raspberry-pi, kali-linux, gui

I did a sudo apt-get update && apt-get upgrade.

After this is done, it no longer boot to GUI.

when I re-start the pi several times, all it does is boot into terminal.

Comment: Try the older kernel.

Comment: Please read this Q/A: https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5360/101265

Comment: Try sudo apt-get --fix-missing update to get missing updates.

then  sudo apt-get dist-upgrade   to install new dependencies   .....  See if this restores the GUI.